# Expose opensource Helm charts through Istio Gateway/VirtualService

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kubernetes-helm

I want to expose some Helm Charts through Istio ingress.

For example, today I can expose Kubernetes Dashboard via `Ingress` type (with NginX Ingress):

`helm install stable/kubernetes-dashboard --set ingress.enabled=true`

However, for Istio **would I have to fork** the Kubernetes Dashboard Helm chart to add the required `Gateway` and `VirtualService` yaml?

Or is there a better way to patch opensource charts to work with Istio ingress?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [kubernetes-dashboard exposing through istio \[1.0.0\] ingress --istio-ingressgateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645124/kubernetes-dashboard-exposing-through-istio-1-0-0-ingress-istio-ingressgatew)

Comment: Nope my question is really if there is an approach or pattern that I can use rather than forking opensource charts. I've updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own chart that includes the `stable/kubernetes-dashboard` as dependency in the `requirements.yaml`. Then you effectively have a wrapper chart that includes the dashboard and you can include the Istio ingress configuration at the wrapper level.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do this without wrapping. In my case I had to expose Keycloak as `VirtualService`. Also keycloak was in other **namespace**.

1. I wrote `Gateway`

`apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: keycloak-gateway
  namespace: keycloak
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"`

2. I wrote `VirtualService`

`apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: demo-keycloak-http
  namespace: keycloak
spec:
  gateways:
  - keycloak-gateway
  hosts:
  - '*'
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /auth
    route:
    - destination:
        host: demo-keycloak-http.keycloak.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80`

Notice that I am routing the service name.
As you can see, it is possible to expose the helm chart from other namespace, in addition. In your case, maybe you will not need to have to write `Gateway`

You just need find the name of service and write for it `VirtualService`.